# Bicgstap алгоритм: ошибка в использовании cublas и cusparse библиотек

Tags: cuda, c++

Привет. Недавно начал учить `cudaC/C++`, решил поупражняться и застрял на какойто не понятной для меня ошибке так как я новичок. Может кто имеет опыт `cudaC/C++` немного помочь с данным кодом. Проблема в цикле `while` который выполняет непосредственно сами итерации алгоритма, насколько я понимаю не изменяется правельно значение переменной dev_r1, в чем я не особо уверен. Цикл в нормальной cudaSample-овской версии итерируется 8 раз а тут он с ума сходит. Никак не могу найти где именно ошибка.

```
// includes, system
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Using updated (v2) interfaces to cublas and cusparse */
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include  <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

// Utilities and system includes
#include <helper_functions.h>  // helper for shared functions common to CUDA Samples
#include <helper_cuda.h>       // helper function CUDA error checking and intialization

const char *sSDKname     = "conjugateGradientManaged";

/* genTridiag: generate a random tridiagonal symmetric matrix */
void genTridiag(int *I, int *J, float *val, int N, int nz)
{
  I[0] = 0, J[0] = 0, J[1] = 1;
  val[0] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX + 10.0f;
  val[1] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
  int start;

  for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
  {
      if (i > 1)
      {
          I[i] = I[i-1]+3;
      }
      else
      {
          I[1] = 2;
      }

      start = (i-1)*3 + 2;
      J[start] = i - 1;
      J[start+1] = i;

      if (i < N-1)
      {
          J[start+2] = i + 1;
      }

      val[start] = val[start-1];
      val[start+1] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX + 10.0f;

      if (i < N-1)
      {
          val[start+2] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      }
  }

  I[N] = nz;
}

__global__ void set_b(float *b, float *r1, float *r0)
{
 *b = *r1 / *r0;

 //printf("%f\n", b);

}

__global__ void set_a(float *a, float *r1, float *dot)
{

  //printf("%f\n", a);

  *a = *r1 / *dot;
  //printf("%f\n", a);

}

__global__ void set_na(float *na, float *a)
{

  *na = -*a;
  //printf("%f\n", na);

}

__global__ void set_r0(float *r0, float *r1)
{

  *r0 = *r1;
  //printf("%f\n", r0);

}

__global__ void set_kernel_var(float *alpha, float *beta, float *alpham1)
{

  *alpha = 1.0;
  *alpham1 = -1.0;
  *beta = 0.0; 
  printf("%f\n", alpha);

}
//loat dev_a, dev_b, dev_na, dev_r0, dev_r1;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int cpu_nz = 0, *cpu_I = NULL, *cpu_J = NULL;
  int N = 0, *dev_N,  *dev_nz, *dev_I = NULL, *dev_J = NULL; // = 0,

  float *cpu_val = NULL;
  float *dev_val = NULL;

  const float cpu_tol = 1e-5f;
  //const float dev_tol = 1e-5f;

  float cpu_r1;
  float *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_na, *dev_r0, *dev_r1;

  const int cpu_max_iter = 10000;

  float *cpu_x;
  float *dev_x;

  float *cpu_rhs;
  float *dev_rhs;

  //./float  dev_r1;

  float *dev_dot;

  float *cpu_r, *cpu_p, *cpu_Ax;
  float *dev_r, *dev_p, *dev_Ax;

   int cpu_k;

  float *dev_alpha, *dev_beta, *dev_alpham1;

  printf("Starting [%s]...\n", sSDKname);

  // This will pick the best possible CUDA capable device
  cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
  int devID = findCudaDevice(argc, (const char **)argv);
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID));

  // Statistics about the GPU device
  printf("> GPU device has %d Multi-Processors, SM %d.%d compute capabilities\n\n",
         deviceProp.multiProcessorCount, deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);

  /* Generate a random tridiagonal symmetric matrix in CSR format */
  N = 1048576;
  cpu_nz = (N-2)*3 + 4;

  cpu_I = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(N+1));                            // csr row pointers for matrix A
  cpu_J = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*cpu_nz);                               // csr column indices for matrix A
  cpu_val = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*cpu_nz);                         // csr values for matrix A

  genTridiag(cpu_I, cpu_J, cpu_val, N, cpu_nz);

  cpu_x = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*N); 
  cpu_rhs = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*N);

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
      cpu_rhs[i] = 1.0;
      cpu_x[i] = 0.0;
  }

  /* Get handle to the CUBLAS context */
  cublasHandle_t cublasHandle = 0;
  cublasStatus_t cublasStatus;
  cublasStatus = cublasCreate(&cublasHandle);

  checkCudaErrors(cublasStatus);

  /* Get handle to the CUSPARSE context */
  cusparseHandle_t cusparseHandle = 0;
  cusparseStatus_t cusparseStatus;
  cusparseStatus = cusparseCreate(&cusparseHandle);

  checkCudaErrors(cusparseStatus);

  cusparseMatDescr_t descr = 0;
  cusparseStatus = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descr);

  checkCudaErrors(cusparseStatus);

  cusparseSetMatType(descr,CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
  cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descr,CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

  // temp memory for CG
  cpu_r = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float)); //
  cpu_p = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float)); //
  cpu_Ax = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float)); //

  for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
  {
      cpu_r[i] = cpu_rhs[i];

  }

  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_r, N*sizeof(float)));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_p, N*sizeof(float)));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_Ax, N*sizeof(float)));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_I, sizeof(int)*(N+1)));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_J, sizeof(int)*cpu_nz));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_val, sizeof(float)*cpu_nz));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_x, sizeof(float)*N));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_rhs, sizeof(float)*N));

  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_a, sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_b, sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_r1, sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_r0, sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_na, sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_nz, sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_N, sizeof(int));

  cudaMemcpy(dev_I, cpu_I, sizeof(int)*(N+1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_J, cpu_J, sizeof(int)*cpu_nz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_val, cpu_val, sizeof(float)*cpu_nz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_x, cpu_x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_rhs, cpu_rhs, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_r, cpu_r, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_Ax, cpu_Ax, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(dev_p, cpu_p, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_alpha, sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_alpham1, sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_beta, sizeof(float));

  set_kernel_var<<<1, 1>>>(dev_alpha, dev_beta, dev_alpham1);

  cublasSetPointerMode(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE);
  cusparseSetPointerMode(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE);

  cusparseScsrmv(cusparseHandle,CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, N, cpu_nz, 
          dev_alpha, descr, dev_val, dev_I, dev_J, dev_x, dev_beta, dev_Ax);

  cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle, N, dev_alpham1, dev_Ax, 1, dev_r, 1);

  cublasStatus = cublasSdot(cublasHandle, N, dev_r, 1, dev_r, 1, dev_r1);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaMemcpy(&cpu_r1, dev_r1, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cpu_k = 1;

printf("%i\n", cpu_r1);

  while (cpu_r1 > cpu_tol*cpu_tol && cpu_k <= cpu_max_iter)
  {

      if (cpu_k > 1)
      {

          set_b<<<1, 3>>>(dev_b, dev_r1, dev_r0);

          cublasStatus = cublasSscal(cublasHandle, N, dev_b, dev_p, 1);
          cublasStatus = cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle, N, dev_alpha, dev_r, 1, dev_p, 1);
      }

      else
      {
          cublasStatus = cublasScopy(cublasHandle, N, dev_r, 1, dev_p, 1);
      }

      cusparseScsrmv(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, N, 
              cpu_nz, dev_alpha, descr, dev_val, dev_I, dev_J, dev_p, dev_beta, dev_Ax);

      cublasStatus = cublasSdot(cublasHandle, N, dev_p, 1, dev_Ax, 1, dev_dot);
      set_a<<<1, 1>>>(dev_a, dev_r1, dev_dot);

      cublasStatus = cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle, N, dev_a, dev_p, 1, dev_x, 1);
      set_na<<<1, 1>>>(dev_na, dev_a);

      cublasStatus = cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle, N, dev_na, dev_Ax, 1, dev_r, 1);
      set_r0<<<1,1>>>(dev_r0, dev_r1);

      cublasStatus = cublasSdot(cublasHandle, N, dev_r, 1, dev_r, 1, dev_r1);
      cudaMemcpy(&cpu_r1, dev_r1, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

      printf("iteration = %3d, residual = %e\n", cpu_k, sqrt(cpu_r1));

      cpu_k++;//
  }

  printf("Final residual: %e\n",sqrt(cpu_r1));

  fprintf(stdout,"&&&& uvm_cg test %s\n", (sqrt(cpu_r1) < cpu_tol) ? "PASSED" : "FAILED");

  cudaMemcpy(cpu_I, dev_I, sizeof(int)*(N+1), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(cpu_J, dev_J, sizeof(int)*cpu_nz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(cpu_val, dev_val, sizeof(float)*cpu_nz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  float rsum, diff, err = 0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
      rsum = 0.0;

      for (int j = cpu_I[i]; j < cpu_I[i+1]; j++)
      {
          rsum += cpu_val[j]*cpu_x[cpu_J[j]];
      }

      diff = fabs(rsum - cpu_rhs[i]);

      if (diff > err)
      {
          err = diff;
      }
  }

  cusparseDestroy(cusparseHandle);
  cublasDestroy(cublasHandle);

  cudaFree(dev_I);
  cudaFree(dev_J);
  cudaFree(dev_val);
  cudaFree(dev_x);
  cudaFree(dev_r);
  cudaFree(dev_p);
  cudaFree(dev_Ax);
  cudaFree(dev_rhs);

  delete [] cpu_I;
  delete [] cpu_J;
  delete [] cpu_val;
  delete [] cpu_x;
  delete [] cpu_r;
  delete [] cpu_p;
  delete [] cpu_Ax;
  delete [] cpu_rhs;

  cudaDeviceReset();

  printf("Test Summary:  Error amount = %f, result = %s\n", err, 
          (cpu_k <= cpu_max_iter) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE");
  exit((cpu_k <= cpu_max_iter) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: все решено

Comment: @qnek, По возможности пуликуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.